# Trouble logging in with DotnetOpenAuth in asp.net 4.5 sample application

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I am just trying to see how open auth works in asp.net 4.5 application.

I just created a new template and it has the deafult code for handling google.

I just un commented the comments as per instructions to enable it, but when i run the application and click on login, it is throwing an exception instead of redirecting to google login page

**[image: Here is the screen shot of the error:]**

I have to cross the proxy to make the outbound requests.  I guess it is what is blocking it to connect to google.

**Is there any way to cross through proxy and make the request ?  please suggest**

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304064/specifying-a-proxy-to-use-with-dotnetopenid

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy then you will need to tell ASP.NET which proxy it should use - this is to do with .NET rather than DotNetOpenAuth.  As mentioned by @IsThatSo have a look at [**Specifying a proxy to use with DotNetOpenID**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304064/specifying-a-proxy-to-use-with-dotnetopenid) which details that you how you specify the proxy to use.

```
system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy
      usesystemdefault = "False"
      proxyaddress="http://myproxyserver:8080"
      bypassonlocal="True"
    />
    <bypasslist>
      <add address="[a-z]+\.mydomain\.com"/>
      <add address="[a-z]+\.myotherdomain\.com"/>
    </bypasslist>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: where do i have to provide the credentials ?

Comment: You have two options, 1. make sure your app pool runs under an account with access through your proxy, or 2. Implement your own proxy `public class MyProxy: IWebProxy{...}` and specify that proxy module in your web.config [As exampled here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/194414/20406)